# Error loading index.jsp in production but no in dev enviroment

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, tomcat

I'm working in a Java + Spring + Hibernate webbapp running in Tomcat 9.0.

The app deployed on production server (Tomcat) doesn´t work ok.

I have found a strange problem coming back to index.jsp.

When I'm in a page "X" and want to go back to index page, it just loads the same page.

Code in one of the controllers:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView cargarInicio() throws Exception {  
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
    return mv;
}
```

This is the link in jsp:

```
<a  href="">Back to login</a>
```

In dev it works ok.

Comment: why is `href` is empty? it will be defaulted to `#`.

Comment: Try `a href="/"`

Comment: Thanks! It is working now.

Comment: Can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure you direct to root, use

```
<a href="/">Back to login</a>
```